# MySQL DELETE post_content from all posts except specific category

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I need a SQL query that update post_content column from all posts except this category ID = 2365
I tried many codes but I still can not find the solution

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content='' WHERE LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id NOT IN (2365)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
 UPDATE wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
set wp_posts='' 
WHERE wp_posts.id not in (
select wp_posts.id from wp_posts 
inner join wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
inner join wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id  =2365)
```

Comment: you mean set post_content=' ' :D

Comment: I just use your condition since i don't what what value you want to set here. :)

Comment: I tested it. this code will delete all post_content including exclude cat. for example a post is in both category {2365,5} and I don't want to delete this post's content but other posts in category 3 should be delete

Comment: Got you. Let me try again. Is it possible to send me table structures and insert statement through mail?

Comment: Is post_id (object_id) available in wp_term_taxonomy table?

Comment: no there is not. there are term_taxonomy_id,term_id,taxonomy,description,parent and count

Comment: I have updated my answer to avoid all the posts for which term_id with 2365 exists.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

Comment: A bracket was missing at the end.